# Early Universe Flatness Problem

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, curvature, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

My question is about the curvature of spacetime in the early universe (Plank era)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem

Based on data from Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe, in order to achieve the current flatness value for $\Omega$, the density of the early universe can't have departed from its current density by more than one part in $10^{62}$.

This blows my mind, since the mass of the universe is only $10^{56}$ grams. So if there was one gram more, or less, in the universe, it would be significantly curved?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up mass and density. They can only be equivalent if the volume of the observable universe doesn't change when its mass changes, and I don't think we know that (in fact, I would wager the opposite - the expansion of the universe _should be_ affected by its mass).

Answer (score 0):

**The flatness problem**

To understand this we need to use the Friedmann equation$$
\Omega_M+\Omega_\Lambda-1=\frac{k}{a^2H^2}
$$
Where $\Omega_M$ and $\Omega_\Lambda$ correspond to the fraction of matter and dark energy in the universe, k the curvature of the universe($k=-1,0,1$ corresponds to hyperbolic, flat, spherical geometry), $a$ the scale factor and $H^2$ the expansion rate.

we can re-write this as$$
|\Omega_{tot}-1|=\frac{|k|}{\dot{a}^2}
$$
Now when we consider a **matter** dominated universe, goes as $a\sim t^{2/3}$ hence $\dot{a} \sim t^{-1/3}$. When we consider a **radiation** dominated universe $\dot{a}\sim t^{-1/2}$.

Now in both cases the Friedmann equation scales as $$
|\Omega_{tot}-1|\sim t^{2/3}
$$
for a matter dominated universe and
$$
|\Omega_{tot}-1|\sim t
$$
for a radiation dominated universe.

The problem is that over time, the curvature must increase! Only if it's exactly $k=0$ will the curvature stay the same.(This imposes conditions for how close to flat our universe must have been in the very beginning to stay flat until today)

**Inflation solution**

One way to solve this problem is to consider a rapid expansion of the universe. During inflation the scale factor goes as $$a(t)=\exp\left(t\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}\right)$$

This changes the Friedmann equation to $$
|\Omega_{tot}-1| = \frac{3|k|}{\Lambda}\exp\left(-t\sqrt{\frac{4\Lambda}{3}}\right)
$$
Now the expansion of the universe **forces** the curvature back to $k=0$!!